# Camel-Pulsar How to add Transaction in Route

Tags: transactions, apache-camel, pulsar

We have been using apache camel with JMS to route and process messages. We are now considering switching from JMS to using Pulsar. I have been experimenting with the camel-pulsar component but can't find any documentation on how to use the component. With JMS, it is possible to create a transaction on the route. Is bit possible to have a transaction with pulsar, so that if processing fails the message is returned to pulsar? Also, is there any documentation on the camel-pulsar component apart from the code in gitlab?

Many Thanks

Bruce

Can't find method to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions is only for JTA/XA capable resources which very often is old technologies like JMS and JDBC.

Kafka / Pulsar does not work with that, and have their own *pseudo* transaction.

With kafka transaction then you can make it so that all kafka interactions can be in the same transaction, but not when you mix in other resources like JMS or JDBC databases.

I assume its the same for Apache Pulsar (however I don't 100% know).

The camel-pulsar consumer will acknowledge the message after the route is complete. You can turn this off and use manual acknowledgement, then you need to call acknowledge from java code yourself.

Comment: Thanks Claus, I'll check out how to do that.